# Error opening .mdf file through SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

I am doing a project of a web enabled database. I have created the database file in my PC.

Now when I just want to open .mdf i.e. of the database I created, I cannot open it in other PC. I even had copied the .ldf file i.e the log file to that PC.

Since I need to transfer the database to the Server later, I don't know how I will dump the database in that server from my PC so that the company can use it.

Comment: What error is the studio showing when you try to open the mdf file? Did you detached it from the parent/original database?

Comment: @Kangkan I had created originally the file in my PC and then when i was checking whether i can store those files in some other PC and open it i could not. In which case i will get the same error when i need to put that database in the Companies Server...the error is "There is no editor available for 'C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSQLServer\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\Student.mdf' Make sure the application for the file type (.mdf) is installed" 
Where as i have Installed SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of using mdf file is like this:

1. Create a new database using SQL Server (set the path for the file as you wish)
2. If you wish to move the file elsewhere,

   - detach the database from your server
   - copy/move the file to wherever you wish
   - attach the file as database in SQL server

You are not supposed to open the file by double-clicking as mime setting or attachment of extensions migh not be there in the target machine.

Why don't you use the decent method to copy/move database?

Comment: Thanks. I got it.. I am a new user and was learning and also doing this project. so was confused. Regarding the columns it has. i.e. it has options while dettaching
 "drop","update" and "keep"
 what does it mean? i tried option of keep being disabled and enabled it works perfectly the same!!

Comment: The headers of the columns detail out what they mean. "Drop" relates to whether you wish to drop the users connected to the database at that time. "Update" is for whether you wish to update statistics and "Keep" relates to whether you wish to keep the full text catalog.